# What is the importance of Pseudo Device Files and In what scenarios should I use them?

Tags: linux, file

I was browsing through [Device_files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file)  and encountered psuedo device files. I do understand the concept of they not being physically present . But what i do not understand is the need of having such files? and what scenarios should i use them ?
Also, in what kinda of applications will pseudo device files be helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

1. **/dev/null**
   Used mostly in shell scripts when you want to discard one of the standard streams e.g.:
   If you ***are not*** root try:

`find /root -name '*.cpp' 2> /dev/null`

and then:

`find /root -name '*.cpp'`

First one will give you no error messages because they are printed to standard error stream (represented as file descriptor number **2**) and this stream was redirected to a bottomless hole (aka /dev/null)

1. **/dev/zero**
   If you want to read as many zeros as you want e.g. you may want to create a file full of zeros (again using shell script) or (more common) zero some device (think: disk partition)
2. **/dev/random** and **/dev/urandom**
   Used a lot when a (relatively) good source of random data is needed (e.g. in cryptography when you want to 'seed' some algorithm). This is especially handy because you have pseudo-random generator out of the box.
3. **/dev/full**
   Very useful for testing: e.g. if you want to test how your application would behave when you run out of disk space (without actually filling all of your disk :))

Comment: Loop devices are another kind of pseudo devices with interesting applications. Nicely explained here -> http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/12a-specialfs.html